# How to disable Windows Defender via PowerShell on Windows 10 version 1903+?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-defender

So, I need to automatically disable Windows Defender for certain virtual machines via a PowerShell script. Previous to the May update, one could set the `DisableAntiSpyware` and `DisableRoutinelyTakingAction` in the registry and Defender was disabled.

Now with version 1903, this doesn't seem to work anymore. Even with disabling the Anti temper protection via registry and rebooting, I only get a permission denied when trying to set the two registry values.

Does anyone have ideas how I could solve this? I tried using the [Invoke-CommandAs](https://github.com/mkellerman/Invoke-CommandAs) to do this as SYSTEM, however this didn't work either sadly.

Comment: Please provide some details on the properties of those two keys.  You might want to try adding the user who runs the script to the list of users with read/write access.

Comment: So, are you saying, you want no AV on those hosts?  Historically, if so, MP gets disabled when you install another AV solution.

Comment: The two keys disable the on-demand scanner and Windows Defender automatically taking action if it detects anything (e.g. scheduled scan).
Yes, I want no AV on these hosts. They're just virtual machines for security research, so an AV on those would be pretty annoying.

Comment: The typical answer to OP's question would be to use Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false However, it seems that since 1903 update (the Windows version which OP is asking about), Microsoft has disabled this ability - and there seems to be a complete lack of information about it online right now.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I guess I found a way.

Either use [Defender Control](https://www.sordum.org/9480/defender-control-v1-5/) or elevate a PowerShell session TrustedInstall (SYSTEM is not enough!), stop and disable the service and afterwards create the registry key. For elevation, I used the seperate tool [RunAsTi](https://github.com/jschicht/RunAsTI).

This is what I used:

```
Stop-Service WinDefend
Set-Service WinDefend -StartupType Disabled
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" -Name "DisableAntiSpyware" -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" -Name "DisableRoutinelyTakingAction" -Value 1
```

Now, this works so far. However, I still need to automate it that it works completely standalone, e.g. I have to develop the elevation part in PowerShell.

Comment: is there any way to run PS as TrustedInstall w/o any 3rd party tools?

Comment: It's not quite w/o 3rd party tools, but you can use the [NTObjectManager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NtObjectManager/1.1.22) in combination with its `New-Win32Process` to spawn a PS instance as a child from trustedinstaller.exe. Internally, I have used this as a solution: Install the NtObjectManager module, start the TrustedInstaller service, use `New-Win32Process` and run powershell with the above commands encoded.

Comment: UPD: RunAsTi seems not working anymore. Can't catch crash log because it spawns in new cmd instance and instantly disappears. I found NSudo working nice.
https://github.com/M2Team/NSudo