# How to disable Windows 10 defender in windows 10 home 1909

Tags: windows-defender

I need an effective way to permanently shut down the defender services iam using home version the local group policy editor doesn't exist, and the hkey local machine method doesn't work on the latest update the folder doesn't exist

Comment: [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i) might help you.

Comment: Why are we teaching people how to make there environment less safe?

Comment: There are many reasons to disable something, could be temporary for troubleshooting.  Could be a budding security professional - learning the markers of compromise, etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Windows Defender via PowerShell on Windows 10 version 1903+?](https://superuser.com/questions/1447884/how-to-disable-windows-defender-via-powershell-on-windows-10-version-1903)

Answer (score 1):

As you have the Home edition of Windows, gpedit.msc doesn't exist. In that case, you should get the same effect by opening the registry (regedit) and navigate to the key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender

You will then probably need to create the following 2 DWORD values:

DisableAntiSpyware set to 1

ServiceKeepAlive set to 0

Then restart.

Note: Installing other reputable security software will typically disable Defender as well.

Now, depending on the version of Windows, you may have to open the Security settings and disable Tamper Protection for the above registry keys to stick. After the restart, if you open Services.msc, the Windows Defender Anti-Virus service should be stopped.

Comment: [This no longer works as of August 2020](https://www.onmsft.com/news/microsoft-removes-regedit-ability-to-disable-microsoft-defender)